# How to return list from another class without creating infinite loop?

Tags: c#

I have separate classes for Player and Team. I would like to return a list (Players) to the Team class of all the players that match their same teamid. I have managed to do this with the Player class (finding the one individual team that matches the player's teamid) but when attempting to do this with a list in the Team class I get an infinite loop error.

I'll show you guy the code I was attempting to use but there has to be a much easier way to do this. I think the reason this is happening is because the players are generated AFTER the the file is loaded but the teams are created when opening the game (I'm still doing a lot of testing so teams are generated when I open the game instead of on a button click like player generation).

I'm also thinking the infinite loop happens because Form1 is being called in Team.cs.. I just don't know how to do this so any help is appreciated!

So on Player.cs I have the following code (which works very well):

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();

    public Team Team
    {
        get
        {
            return f1.getTeams.Find(x => x.teamid == teamid);
        }
    }
```

Since Form1 is already instantiated when creating players (its a button click on the program currently but later it will be on league creation instead of a button) the above code works.

If you guys can help me find a way without using Form1 that would be great too. But the main problem at the moment is the below code which creates an infinite loop.

On Team.cs I have the following code, but its not working:

```
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();

    //THIS IS CREATING AN INFINITE LOOP... THERE HAS TO BE ANOTHER WAY TO FIND THE PLAYERS WITH THE SAME TEAMID???
    public List<Player> Players
    {
        get
        {
            Player player = f1.getPlayers.Find(
                delegate (Player p) { return p.teamid == teamid; });

            foreach (Player p in players)
            {
                Players.Add(p);
            }

            return Players;
        }
    }
```

This is what is inside of getPlayers:

```
public List<Player> getPlayers
    {
        get
        {
            return listOfPlayers;
        }
        set
        {
            listOfPlayers = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `players` refer to?

Comment: `Player p in players` just return `players` probably but your but your code is incomplete.

Comment: Hmm please take one step back and try to re engineer your model. you are right. there can be better ways if your model is designed properly.

Comment: players is the list on the Team.cs. My hope is to create that list by finding the players that match their teamid.

Comment: Try posting a MCVE, described at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Just make a console application and get rid of the Forms and extra complexity. Then let's look at how the two classes interact.

Comment: I guess I'll have to look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need your getter to create its own list and return that list. As is, you're referencing `Players` from *inside of* the `Players` getter, hence you'll get a stack overflow due to infinite recursion.

Fix:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

public IList<Player> Players
{
    get
    {
        // Assuming that `.Find(...)` returns an `IEnumerable<Player>`
        return f1.getPlayers.Find(p => p.teamid == teamid).ToList()
    }
}
```

(if `f1.getPlayers.Find(...)` doesn't create an IEnumerable, you can keep the loop pattern instead):

```
public IList<Player> Players
{
    get
    {
        var result = new List<Player>();
        foreach (var player in f1.getPlayers.Find(p => p.teamid == teamid))
        {
            result.Add(player);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Update**:

Since we can now see that `f1.getPlayers` returns a `List<Player>`, this is more appropriate (`Where` filters a list, as opposed to `Find` which returns just one match):

```
public IList<Player> Players
{
    get
    {
        return f1.getPlayers.Where(p => p.teamid == teamid).ToList()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting an error on ToList()

'Player' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'Player' can be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq;`? If so, it might be that `.Find()` is not an `IEnumerable<Player>`.

Comment: I do have using System.Linq

Comment: I just tried using your second one and I'm now getting this error on foreach.... foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Indoor_Football_Manager.Player' because '...Player' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @RobertCole what is `getPlayers()`, you need to update your question with the definition

Comment: getPlayers returns the list of players generated when the button is clicked. Edited my original post to include that.

Comment: @RobertCole [Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a single `Player` so you cannot iterate over it.

Comment: So how can I return a list of players then?

Comment: You probably want `.Where(...)`, not `.Find(...)`.